# Search Issue After Disabling Windows 11 Bing Search

Tags: windows, windows-registry, search, bing

I have encountered a problem where I couldn't access environment variables after disabling Bing search via:

1. <kbd>[image: WinKey]</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> → *Open:* `regedit` → OK
2. Created new DWORD `BingSearchEnabled` with value `0` within:

   ```
   HKCU\software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Search
   ```

After making these changes, I noticed that *Change environment variables* option no longer appears when I search for `env` or other keywords, and restarting the computer did not resolve the issue.

- When I revert the changes by deleting DWORD `BingSearchEnabled`, the issue goes away and I can access environment variables again
- Although I haven't found similar reports of this specific problem, it seems that disabling Bing search affects the visibility of various options beyond just search keyword `env`.

If anyone has encountered a similar issue or has insights into resolving this problem in Windows 11, I would greatly appreciate your assistance, as restoring access to the environment variables is crucial for my workflow.

Comment: There shouldn't be any correlation between the two. In any case, the Start menu option is called "Edit the system environment variables" and not "Change environment variables".

Comment: I was unable to reproduce the behavior you describe on any of my Windows 11 machines

Comment: Sorry. I just translated the key because my language on the machine isn't English. Forgot to mention that. Is this related?

Comment: Also if I search with my system language with direct keywords, the search result can return.